# Word/words to describe someone who completes a task in a very quick time, despite having no obligation to do so?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-requests, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

My professor incorrectly inputted a grade of mine and I emailed him to alert him of this error.

Context: In my experience, professors take an ungodly amount of time to correct a mistake.  I was expecting to not receive a response or a correction for several days or even weeks.

My professor within a span of three hours, emailed me his sincerest apologies for his error, corrected the grade, and assured me this would never happen again.  Another detail - we are on spring break.

I want to thank him for this, so . . . "Word/words to describe someone who completes a task in a very quick time, despite having no obligation to do so?"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example sentence in which you would use the word(s).

Comment: "Assured me this would never happen again." He would rank only alongside the Pope in his infallibility.

Comment: It is a very _prompt_ response and worthy, indeed, of a thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To act with **dispatch**, **expeditious**. I would say that these are a bit too pedantic sounding for an email. **Prompt** is a bit better, though I personally would express it with simple English.

Comment: I did not consider that it can perceived as even more polite to explain my testament, rather than use a word that, best case scenario, most likely **alludes** to the meaning behind it.

Comment: Just write him a quick thank-you note.  The sooner you write it the briefer you can be.

Answer (score 0):

[On-call](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+call)

I think It can be a suitable word for your description.

> On-call: (of a person)able to be contacted in order to provide a professional service if necessary but not formally on duty

You can say: thanks for being on-call